# filter items in an underscore template

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

I'm trying to filter out elements in an [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) template. For example I want only to return the elements that do not have a class name of "pin". Anyone know how I could do that either with underscore methods or jquery

```
var renderToHTML = function( data ) {
    var list = data.results[0].items;
    var tmpl = $( template({items : list}) );
    // var layout = tmpl.filter()
}
```

My template code looks like this.

```
<% _.each(items,function(item,i){ %> 
    <% var cls=( item.id == 'feature') ? "pin" : 'item'; %>
    <div class="<%=cls%> <%=item.id%>" style="width:<%=item.width%>px">
        <div class="itemInner">
            <img src="<%= item.img %>" />
            <div class="title"><%= item.title %></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% }); %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract the `<div>`s without a class of `pin` from the generated HTML, then you'd probably want to use [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$(':not(.pin)')
$('some_prefix_for_specificity :not(.pin)')
$some_root_element.find(':not(.pin)')
//...
```

Or, given the logic inside your template, you might be able to look for `.item` instead:

```
$('.item')
$('some_prefix_for_specificity .item')
$some_root_element.find('.item')
//...
```

If you only want to include non-`pin`s in the HTML that comes out of your template, then:

```
<% _.each(items, function(item, i) { %>
    <% if(item.id != 'feature') { %>
        <div class="item <%= item.id %>" style="width: <%= item.width %>px">
            <!--...-->
        </div>
    </div>
<% }); %>
```

Or perhaps use [`_.chain`](http://underscorejs.org/#chain) and [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter):

```
<% _(items).chain().filter(function(item) { return item.id != 'feature' }).each(function(item, i) { %>
    <div class="item <%= item.id %>" style="width: <%= item.width %>px">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
<% }); %>
```

If you want to do it at this level:

```
var tmpl = $(template({items : list}));
```

Then you'd want to use jQuery's [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
var not_pins = tmpl.filter(':not(.pin)');
```

or, again, given the specific structure of your template:

```
var not_pins = tmpl.filter('.item');
```

Comment: Thanks for all this. .find does not work on a template even when wrapped with jquery. I guess it has to be appended to the dom first for it to work. I tried using not on just the tmpl elements but it still returns elements that have a class called pin.   var tmpl = $( template({items : list}) );
  var temp = $(tmpl, ':not(pin)');

Comment: Also I want to do it outside the template and before I append the template to the DOM tree.So when it is at this stage.   var tmpl = $( template({items : list}) );

Comment: @Chapsterj: Sounds like you want to use `filter` then, I've updated my answer to reflect your comment.